# Page coming up blank after I compile PHP and PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql

**Problem**

I am having a problem displaying the page after I compiled this code, but I cannot see what is wrong with it and I cannot debug due to it not appearing on the web.

**PHP and PostgreSQL Code:**

```
<?php       
    // Connecting, selecting database
    $dbconn = pg_connect("host=*****  port=*****
    dbname=***** user=***** password=*****")
    or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());

    //collect
    if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
        $searchq = $_POST['search'];
        $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i"."".$searchq);

    // Performing SQL query
    $query = "SELECT * FROM enumbers WHERE code LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die ("could not search!");
       $result = query($query);
    if($result = 0){
        $output = 'There is no such E-Number!'
    }else{
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $code = $row['code'];
            $name = $row['name'];
            $type = $row['type'];
            $vegan = $row['vegan'];

            $output .= '<div> '.vegan.' ';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

**The Form and Printing Code:**

```
 <div id="tablebox">
    <!-- Search bar -->
    <p>Is It Vegan?</p>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="searchEnumbers.php">
        <input name="search" type="text" size="30" maxlength="5" />
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>

    <?php
        print("$output");
    ?>
</div>
```

**Update**

I think the problem might be I'm using some MySQL code, but I cannot tell If I am.

Comment: Aguments in `preg_replace` should be divided by `,`

Comment: Other errors can be found by turning error_reporting `on`

Comment: Like so: $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using mysql_fetch_array instead of postgres method. Please see the sample

```
    <?php 
    // Connecting, selecting database
    $dbconn = pg_connect("host=****  port=****
    dbname=**** user=**** password=****")
    or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
     $output = '';

    //collect
    if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
        $searchq = $_POST['search'];
        // $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i"."".$searchq);

    // Performing SQL query
    $query = "SELECT * FROM enumbers WHERE code LIKE '%$searchq%'";
    $ret = pg_query($dbconn, $query);
   if(!$ret){
      echo pg_last_error($dbconn);
      exit;
   } 
   $output = '';
   while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($ret)){
            $code = $row['code'];
            print_r($row);
            $name = $row['name'];
            $type = $row['type'];
            $vegan = $row['vegan'];

            $output .= '<div> '.vegan.' ';
   }
}
   echo "Operation done successfully\n";
   pg_close($dbconn);

?>
```

Comment: May I copy and paste this, and change things so it fits mine?

Comment: No, this is general example. Let me update it so it fits your example.

Comment: @RushFan2112 Please check now. i have updated the answer & let me know if it works for you

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: It is still displaying a blank page

Comment: Ohh! Please remove the last ')' from this line
    `$query = "SELECT * FROM enumbers WHERE code LIKE '%$searchq%'") ;`
Also please close the bracket for isset statement

Comment: It is still coming up with a blank page, or a "white screen of death", http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death

Comment: Thank you for your help Agam, means a lot

Comment: I think there is syntax error here for isset bracket. Also you can check the apache error logs why its showing blank screen. In ubuntu its usually located in /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: Fixed the syntax. Please check the answer &  Check now. Also i have commented the preg_replace for now. Try with this

Comment: That has fixed the blank screen, thank you! It now does this: http://users.aber.ac.uk/sec17/veganomnia/searchEnumbers.php

Comment: Yes in while loop, there is print command. you can comment it. Also please upvote & mark as accepted if i solved your query